# Is there any way to merge pdf files by downloading it from remote urls without saving it on my server using node js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, url, merge, stream

I want to merge PDF files from remote URLs without saving source files completely on disk. I am looking for something like stream for pdf merging with NodeJs.

I have merge pdf files using node-pdftk with source files stored locally. But what if i have the URLs of the source files and i don't want to store the source files completely on disk.

```
const pdftk = require('node-pdftk');
pdftk.input({
    A: './co.pdf',
    B: './dummy.pdf',
})
.cat('A B')
.output('./merged.pdf')
.catch(err => {
    // handle errors
    console.log(err);
});
```

I want to give input of source files from remote URLs. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation says:
 The `.input` method will accept a buffer, file path, or an array of buffer/file paths. It will then initialize the input of the command.
So you can download a remote file store in a buffer without saving it to disk and pass buffer as below:

```
 pdftk.input({
            A: bufferA
            B: bufferB
        })
```

You can download a file as a buffer like below

```
const request = require("request-promise-native");
let pdfBuffer = await request.get({uri: pdfURL, encoding: null});
```

Comment: You are right but still the whole pdf data will save in RAM , because buffer uses RAM. The problem remains same.